# addslashes and json_encode not working together

Tags: php, json, addslashes

```
$val = "I'm string";
```

For this type of string I am using the addslashes function, which convert string into like this:

```
"I\'m string"
```

and store into the database. When I get all data from database in array of fields and passed array in

```
json_encode($arr);
```

In response I get the string with a extra slash like this:

```
"I\\'m string"
```

And I wanted to remove that extra slash which is added by json_encode. how I do that??

Comment: You shouldn't be using addslashes with databases.  Use prepared statements.  It looks like you're actually adding a literal slash to your string instead of escaping the apostrophe.

Comment: Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's and this problem dissappears and you dont need **strip** or **add** slashes anywhere

Comment: you all mean to say that I used the prepared statement then no need to used addslashes function

Comment: If you use prepared statement correctly, you don't need addslashes

Comment: prepared statement handle the "I'm" string???

Comment: Yes, without you having to do ANYTHING special at all

Comment: This questions attracts lots of answers which are downvoted. This would not happen if you had shown your code for writing to the database

Comment: here https://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_func_string_addslashes2 it say that it is bad for database queries

Comment: w3schools also used (maybe still) to promote sql injection vulnerable php. There's 4 people here saying you should just use a prepared statement to fix both the root and the symptoms of your problem. Now the answers have a lot of downvotes while they're technically all correct.

Comment: I am not the one who give them downvotes

Comment: That's not the point? The point is that there's 4 correct answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want an answer to this question you can reverse your `addslashes` with `stripslashes`.

But never use addslashes function to escape values you are going to send to mysql.

Use native prepared statements, `mysqli_real_escape_string()` or `PDO::quote`.

**BUT NOTE:**

1. Don't use a vulnerable character set for connection encoding (use
   utf8 or something)
2. Use a higher version of MySQL than 5.7.6.

Read more about character set issues here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.charset.php

Comment: Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)

Comment: Changed my answer to add to the encoding issues.

Comment: It is safe enough if you are using quotes around the variables.

Comment: @RiggsFolly The bug `NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES` was already fixed in 5.7.6. And both functions are safe. But you were right it should mention you need a higher version than 5.7.6. The character issues are documented in PHP docs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`stripslashes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php).

However, you *should* use prepared statements. That way you don't need to worry about escaping your values.

Answer (score -2):

It might even be possible with this (though I thought it was forward slash `/` only:

```
json_encode($array, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

But heed to the comments and Script47's answer and just fix it properly.

Comment: Woah nice, those downvotes. Would love some feedback on my answer since you all think it's clearly wrong? Prepared statements **will** fix OP's problem.